# SQL primary key and foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, schema

Can a primary key of one relation be present on another relation as a foreign key but in a different attribute name? If so, when we provide the relation schema, is it acceptable to give either of the attribute names or does it have a different approach?

ex: say, staff relation has a primary key SID(student ID) and in a separate relation (say, Course) has an attribute named 'student' but contains exact same components as SID. How do we write a relation schema for such scenario?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the question, the answer to your first sentence is "yes, it can". It doesn't matter how you call columns (that's what "attributes" in your text are, I presume); they should match in datatype and - if composite - number of columns (attributes).

For example (this is Oracle; which database do you use?): `t_student` is a *parent* table, it has a primary key set on `student_id` column:

```
SQL> create table t_student
  2    (student_id number       constraint pk_stu primary key,
  3     name       varchar2(30),
  4     birthdate  date
  5    );

Table created.
```

`t_course` is a *child* table. Its `sid` column references `t_student.student_id` column; they don't match in name (which is what you asked), but - they don't match in datatype either:

```
SQL> create table t_course
  2    (course_id  number       constraint pk_cou primary key,
  3     sid        varchar2(10) constraint fk_coustu references t_student(student_id),
  4     name       varchar2(20)
  5    );
   sid        varchar2(10) constraint fk_coustu references t_student(student_id),
   *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type
```

As you can see, it failed. But, if datatype is changed to match parent table's primary key column's datatype, everything is OK:

```
SQL> create table t_course
  2    (course_id  number       constraint pk_cou primary key,
  3     sid        number       constraint fk_coustu references t_student(student_id),
  4     name       varchar2(20)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: @littefoot you nailed it, basically the name of attributes not relevant but datatype need to match.